# Macbook Pro OSX 10.11.6 stopped booting

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

I tried booting my mac today as usual but it turns out that almost immediately the nasty prohibition sign appeared.

I tried the usual stuff: resetting PRAM, SMC and nothing. 
I tried safe mode, but I got that prohibition sign again, so I booted in verbose mode and got the following message:

`efiboot file path: \System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi
 Mach-O file has bad magic number 0x75b873e9
 ERROR!!! Load prelinked kernel with status 0x8000000000000001
 Error loading kernel cache (0x1)`

I'm currently using an external HD with an alternate OS install, and my previous HD appears ok, I can access it, copy files, etc... which leads me to a software problem.

Any ideas???

Comment: It sounds like your EFI and/or boot partition is hosed.  It could be that your hard drive is failing.  If you have access to your files, it would be best that you back it up and do a clean install

Comment: @Allan Thanks, I'm in the process of backing up the HD (~4Tb, so it will take some time). Is there no way to fix the EFI or boot partition?

Comment: It's possible, but without putting hands on, I'm hesitant to mess with it.  Safest and easiest is to just wipe and start over.